# Grails form validation

Tags: grails

What's the simplest way to validate form in grails? I'm not using scalffolding. I also don't want to write those javascript using jquery. I know of the jquery plugin but the documentation not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way?

Use dynamic scaffolding and implement constraints ie

```
class User {

  String name
  String password
  String personalInfo

  static constraints = {
    name(size: 4..20, unique:true, blank:false)
    password(size:8..20, blank:false)
    personalInfo(size: 1000, nullable:true)
  }
}
```

If you don't want to use dynamic scaffolding, you'll have to create the controllers and views for the objects via `grails User generate-all` at the command line.  This will generate the controller and views for the User domain where you can modify at will.  However, this is more complex and you need to be comfortable with GSP tags